# T-SQL IF/ELSE problem

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
IF (@MCODE_VALIDATION = 0)
    INSERT INTO [table].dbo.list VALUES('TEST','TEST','TEST');
    GOTO GENERATE_CHILD;
ELSE 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
    PRINT 'NOT OK'
    GOTO GENERATE_MOTHER;
```

problem in IF part it only allows 1 query

Comment: Don't understand what you're asking. Look at my profile for some articles on how to ask questions here. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Comments have no effect on one's profile. Maybe you'd be better off asking why you have -4 votes on this question? Not me - I've only downvoted 11 times in ~ 5 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your `IF`/`ELSE` in `BEGIN` and `END` statements to execute multiple statements when `@MCODE_VALIDATION = 0` `(IF`) or `@MCODE_VALIDATION != 0` (`ELSE`) .

If you don't, only the first statement will be executed.

**You could do something like this**

```
IF (@MCODE_VALIDATION = 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.list VALUES('TEST','TEST','TEST');
    GOTO GENERATE_CHILD;
END
ELSE --'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'. ?
BEGIN
    PRINT 'NOT OK';
    GOTO GENERATE_MOTHER;
END
```

Comment: Query works, but not the result I expect, Thanks.

Comment: @user3036776 no problem! The result might have something to do with the labels. You could look into adding the statements to the `if` \ `else`blocks instead of using labels